# ASP.NET C# Creating checkboxes from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET, but I need to create checkboxes from a query result.  So far here is what I have.

In my code behind...I pull the query that I need and then create a DataTable from that result like so:

```
DataTable dtLocations = new DataTable();
        dtLocations.Columns.Add("ID");
        dtLocations.Columns.Add("VALUE");
        // Pull locations and add to our datatable
        string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand();
            dbConn.Open();
            dbCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT location_id, location_desc FROM admin_locations WHERE enabled = 'Y'";
            dbCommand.Connection = dbConn;
            SqlDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if (dbReader.HasRows) {
                while (dbReader.Read()) {
                    dtLocations.Rows.Add(new object[] { dbReader["location_id"].ToString(), dbReader["location_desc"].ToString() });
                }
            }
        }
        return dtLocations;
```

I then have a class level var defined as

```
public DataTable dtLocations = new DataTable();
```

which I populate using the method above in my Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(IsPostBack))
    {
        dtLocations = createLocationsDataTable();
    }
}
```

Then in my aspx file (not code behind) I'm doing this to try and create the checkboxes, which needless to say, does not work.

```
<% foreach (DataRow row in dtLocations.Rows) {%>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="idLocationChk" runat="server" Value="<% Response.Write(row["ID"].ToString()); %>" />
                                <% } %>
```

Can someone show me how you're supposed to do this in ASP.NET c#?  I'll also need to be able to get the value of any that are checked in my code behind when a button on the page is clicked.

When I try using a CheckBoxList like this it tells me I can not use codeblocks here.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="message_locations" runat="server">
                                <% foreach (DataRow row in dtLocations.Rows) {%>
                                    <asp:ListItem>TEST</asp:ListItem>
                                <% } %>
                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: You might want to look into a CheckBoxList.

Comment: @VDWWD - any good examples of doing this?  I see this https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/10/checkboxlist-control-example.html but it does not use ID as key VALUE as label for checkbox - it's just all text

Comment: got it.  created my CheckBoxList in front aspx file then create ListItem and add to it from code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a DataTable directly to a CheckBoxList

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dtLocations;
    CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "location_desc";
    CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "location_id";
    CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: This is the most straight forward way to accomplish this, but you can also help clarify that dtLocations needs to be "loaded" first, presumably with   createLocationsDataTable();